Is it possible to qualify a field of a non-qualified data structure?
Is it mandatory to add QUALIFIED to DS1 in order for this code to compile:
**FREE

DCL-DS DS1;
 FIELD1 PACKED(5);
END-DS;

DS1.FIELD1 = 2024; 

DSPLY DS1.FIELD1;

RETURN;

I know the question might sound silly (because what is the purpose of QUALIFIED then?!) but I have a case like this in which they affirm that it compiles.
I have tested it in PUB400.com, it does not compile, but I thought I may be missing some compiler flag or something.

IIRC, originally the compiler would not complain if you used qualified name to reference a non-qualified data structure.
However, IBM "fixed" that bug a while back.
PUB400 tends to stay pretty up to date, so that explains why it doesn't work there.
I'll see if I can find specifics about when this was fixed and update this answer.
UPDATE
A quick search shows this bug was fixed in v7.2, so if you're running a really out of date version of the OS, then that explains why it works on your system.
From the v7.2 Memo to Users

A non-qualified subfield or format cannot be qualified within a subprocedure
It is not valid to use qualified notation, A.B, for subfields and record formats that are not qualified. Before IBM® i 7.2, the compiler did not always detect this error if the reference to the global subfield or record format was in a subprocedure. Starting  in 7.2, the compiler detects this error and diagnostic: RNF7591 - An  operand of a qualified name expression is not valid is issued at  compile time.


Thanks @Charles. It makes sense now. Could you please share where you found that the bug was fixed?

Brief mention of it on the RPG mailing list back in June 2014.

The bug was only related to subprocedures. The compiler didn't complain if you used a qualified name for a subfield in a non-qualified global data structure. It was never allowed to do that in the main procedure, or for a local data structure in a subprocedure.
It's mentioned in the 7.2 Memo to Users. https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.2?topic=wds-ile-rpg-changes

@BarbaraMorris so the OP's example shouldn't have worked anywhere?  Since it's in mainline.  Interesting...I suspect they over simplified their example.  Now tell us, did you recall the specifics, or did my link to your RPG mailing list post send you looking at your notes?  :D

@Charles I remembered that it was in a Memo to Users. It wasn't until after I found the MTU link that I clicked on your link and saw that it was a post from me. Double :-D :-D

Indeed, I over simplified the example. @BarbaraMorris I appreciate your effort looking up the MTU link.
